# What happens when external force on a body equals force of limiting friction?

Tags: classical-mechanics, friction

What happens when external force on a body equals force of limiting friction?
I wanted to know if it stays at rest or starts motion.

Comment: Net force is zero so stays at rest.

Comment: Note that this is a bit like asking "What happens to a glass of water that is half on the table and half hanging over the edge?"  In the real world, neither the limiting friction nor the external force will be perfectly measurable nor perfectly constant.  If the answer is important, you'd better assume the worst case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be on the verge of moving or slipping

Answer (score 0):

The net forces on a (rigid) object determine its acceleration.  If the total force is zero, it will remain at rest.